# Adding leading zeros to Oracle number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database and run a query to find the number of rows and then insert it into a field (row_count) with a max field length of 9.  How can I add leading 0's to the front of whatever number is returned in this query?

```
SQLExec("select count(*) from PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL", &row_count);

INSERT INTO sqltable VALUES &rowcount;
```

So if the count is 38485 I would want to insert '000038485'

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has the `lpad()` function:

```
INSERT INTO sqltable
    select lpad(&rowcount, 9, '0') from dual;
```

By the way, it is good practice to include the column list when doing an insert:

```
INSERT INTO sqltable(column)
    select lpad(&rowcount, 9, '0') from dual;
```